# How to create a live website thumbnail as preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to create a gallery in React with life previews of many websites (like a portfolio) all the linked websites belong to me as well.
I already try to use iFrame and embed but I didn't have the result I would like, I'm trying to get a miniature website like in here https://codesandbox.io/explore.
[image]

Even tho the website show the thumbnails as images if you update your sandbox it will the images will update too.

I try use iFrame and embed but it does not show a small version of the website but the website as a mobile and just the frame size.

Any ideas in how I could generate such images or solve this problem in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this on the front end in a webpage. You need to execute something like puppeteer on your backend to screenshot the pages. An example can be found on
https://bitsofco.de/using-a-headless-browser-to-capture-page-screenshots/

Answer (score -1):

To create a gallery in React with live previews of multiple websites, you can use the "react-iframe" library. This library allows you to embed iframes into your React components and control their behavior.
First, you need to install the "react-iframe" library

```
npm install react-iframe
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import Iframe from 'react-iframe';

const WebsitePreview = ({ url }) => {
  return (
    <div className="website-preview">
      <Iframe url={url} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default WebsitePreview;
```

If you want to generate thumbnails of websites programmatically, you can use a third-party service or library that provides this functionality like Puppeteer.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://google.com/");
  await page.screenshot({ path: `${uuidv4()}.png`, fullPage: true });
  await browser.close();
})();
```